# How to pass parameter to exists clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, parameter-passing, exists

I have the following method in my model:

> ```
> def is_user_in_role (security_user_id, role)
>   SecurityUser.joins(:security_users_roles)
>               .where(security_users_roles:{role:role})
>               .exists?("security_users.id=#{security_user_id}")
> end
> ```

The issue is that the "security_user_id" is not "translated" correctly in the SQL statements. It is always interpreted as "0".

This is a simple output of the generated SQL passing 'Instructor' and '9' as parameters values:

```
SecurityUser Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM security_users INNER JOIN security_users_manage_securities ON security_users_manage_securities.security_user_id = security_users.id INNER JOIN security_users_roles ON security_users_roles.id = security_users_manage_securities.security_users_role_id WHERE security_users_roles.role = 'Instructor' AND security_users.id = 0 FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

You can see at the end:

```
security_users.id = 0
```

Could you tell me how should I transform the exists clause in order to use it with  parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it. In order to pass parameters in the exists clause, you should use an array like this:

```
def is_user_in_role (security_user_id, role)
  SecurityUser.joins(:security_users_roles)
              .where(security_users_roles:{role:role})
              .exists?(["security_users.id=#{security_user_id}"])
end
```